# How to compare two maps by both key and value and storing difference map in resultant map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Lets say I have two maps:

```
Map mapA = new HashMap();
Map mapB = new HashMap();

mapA.put("JEETENDRA", "24");
mapA.put("AHUJA", "24"); --1A
mapA.put("AHUJA", "25");---2A
mapA.put("PAL", "24");

mapB.put("AHUJA", "24");
mapB.put("JEETENDRA", "24");---1B
mapB.put("PAL", "24");
```

Now i want to compare both maps by both key and value since 2A and 1A have key common.
I know ideally its wrong since key should be unique for map but in code I am retrieving two column record and storing it as map.

MapA is before operations.
MapB is after some operations.

Comment: `mapA` cannot exist and therefore cannot be checked.

Comment: You do realize that value 1A would be removed.  [javadocs read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) "Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced." -- you may need to consider nested data structures such as a `Map<String, Set<String>>` to store where there are multiple values associated with a single key.

Comment: mapA just has one entry for key "AHUJA", since the value of an existing key is overwritten on `put`.

Comment: Could you suggest proper collection which I can use and I dont want to use Guava library of Google specially. Thanks man!!!

Comment: This question really makes no sense.  You want to compare two maps and store "results" but you never indicate what comparison.  Also, you violate basic map behaviour as others have pointed out ("1A" would not exist in the map, "AHUJA" would only have the value of "25" per your code).  You note that is "ideally wrong" (it's not just ideally wrong, it is, in fact, wrong) but make no accommodation or for this or explain what you want.

Comment: Proper collection you can use for what?

Comment: For such scenarios and how i can compare them. This logic is bit new, please excuse for some weird logic written.

Comment: What scenarios?  Are you looking for a MultiValueMap? What does compare mean?

Comment: Step1) First I am getting record from table like ("JEETENDRA", "24"), ("AHUJA", "24"),("AHUJA", "25").Step2) Now after some  code change , I am getting record ("JEETENDRA", "24"), ("AHUJA", "24") so I just want to compare datas retrieved after Step2 and store records in some other collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method, here I have used the Generics, and I have used one TreeMap with name result to hold all keys inside both HashMaps , from this method you will get all the matched objects in Hashmaps

```
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
    Map<K, Boolean> compareKeysAndValues(final Map<K, V> map1,
        final Map<K, V> map2){
        final Collection<K> allKeys = new HashSet<K>();
        allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
        allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());
        final Map<K, Boolean> result = new TreeMap<K, Boolean>();
        for(final K key : allKeys){
            result.put(key,
                map1.containsKey(key) == map2.containsKey(key) &&
                Boolean.valueOf(equal(map1.get(key), map2.get(key))));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and if you want to get the value which are different simply reverse the check in result.put function

Comment: @user3271997 welcome , and if it looks perfect please mark it as a correct by click on the right mark