# Compare two maps by key and value and storing difference into resultant map

Tags: java, hashmap

I know that some of you will mark it as duplicate, but didn't want to ask similar question in someone else thread.
I have two maps:

```
Map<Long, Long> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long, Long) map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

This two maps are different in size.
Maps will look like this:

```
map1        map2
(1,1)       (1,1)
(2,1)       (2,1)
            (3,1)
```

or:

```
map1        map2
(1,1)       (1,1)
(2,1)       (2,1)
            (3,1) 
            (4,1)
```

Now, I wan to create map3 that will contain only difference between map1 and map2, and that is (K,V)-->(3,1) ( (K,V)-->(3,1);(4,1) ). I will then get (K,V) values and use them.
In this thread [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559811/how-to-compare-two-maps-by-both-key-and-value-and-storing-difference-map-in-resu) there is solution but not works for me. Passing to method `compareKeysAndValues(map1,map2)`, receiving: Required Map<Long, Long> provided Map<Long, Boolean)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious solution is to traverse over the keys in both maps and add the entries to the new map if the key doesn't exist in the other map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Long, Long> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Long, Long> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put(1L, 1L);
        map1.put(2L, 1L);
        map1.put(5L, 1L);
        map2.put(1L, 1L);
        map2.put(2L, 1L);
        map2.put(3L, 1L);
        map2.put(4L, 1L);

        Map<Long, Long> map3 = new HashMap<>();

        for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : map1.entrySet()){
            if(!map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                map3.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : map2.entrySet()){
            if(!map1.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                map3.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : map3.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3, 1
4, 1
5, 1
```

Comment: Also, I've assumed you only want to add entries with differing keys to `map3`. If both maps have the same key but different values, it wouldn't be possible to add both to `map3`, so you'd need to decide what you want to do in that context.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details (I was really tired and it was pretty late when I asked), but @Bhaskar your assumption was correct. Your answer really helped me a lot. Due to lack of experience, I would never figure it out to use entrySet.

Comment: Glad I could help :)